# Angular 4 / TypeScript HttpModule Use In Class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a TypeScript class in an Angular 4 app that I want to do something like this:

```
Import { Http } from '@angular/http';

export class Request {
  public url: string;
  public services: string;
  public regions: string;
  public start: Date;
  public end: Date;
  public output: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.url = "https://someurl.com";
    this.services = "All";
    this.regions = "All";
    this.output = "json";
  }

  public Submit() {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe();
    ...
  }
}
```

This would be all well and fine, except in a component, part of my model is the Request class

```
@Component({
selector: "app-request",
styleUrls: [
    './request.component.css'
],
templateUrl: './request.component.html'
})
export class RequestComponent implements OnInit {

  request: Request = new Request();

  ...
}
```

Then the template has several inputs that look like this:

```
<select name="output" id="output" [(ngModel)]="request.output">
        <option *ngFor="let output of outputs" [ngValue]="output">{{output}}</option>
</select>
```

The request object has a bunch of properties that are set as part of `ngModel` and it seems natural that the class object would have a submit method that I can just call directly from the component. However, the `new Request()` fails as it is expecting the Http module object as a parameter. Is this approach not feasible, or how do I inject the Http module as a parameter here?

Comment: I'm not clear about your issue, could you please provide some more code around the request instantiation which is causing the problem?

Comment: Normally your Request class would be a RequestService that you would inject in the component using DI, instead of manually creating new instances. If you have parameters from the model that you want to send, you cloud map those to a RequestParameters object and send that to the request service.

Comment: @SimplyComplexable, I added some additional code to help clarify.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu, that's what I implemented as a "work-around" for this. I moved the submit method into a service and then injected the service into the component and it takes the request as a parameter. I guess that's the angular "way", it's just not typically how I'd structure classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should not be wrapping up your class and service together (maintenance point of view).

However, to answer your question. You will have to make your Request (hybrid service??) an Injectable with annotation `@Injectable()` and make it accessible by providing it into module.

```
Import { Http } from '@angular/http';
Import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Request {
  public url: string;
  public services: string;
  public regions: string;
  public start: Date;
  public end: Date;
  public output: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.url = "https://someurl.com";
    this.services = "All";
    this.regions = "All";
    this.output = "json";
  }

  public Submit() {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe();
    ...
  }
}
```

Now you can get instance in your component constructor.

```
@Component({
selector: "app-request",
styleUrls: [
    './request.component.css'
],
templateUrl: './request.component.html'
})
export class RequestComponent implements OnInit {

  request: Request;

  constructor(
    request:Request){}

}
```

That's a standard angular feature. Ideally, you should make services injectable.